# flutter can't open launch Url google drive

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, url, google-drive-api

when i call launchUrl (url_launcher 6.2.2)
it's not working or outstanding.

I want to open goole drive with link.

```dart
final Uri url = Uri.parse("googel drive link share all people have");     
bool res = await launchUrl(url);
if (!res) {throw Exception('Could not launch url');}
```

Comment: Define it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';


final String googleDriveLink = "https://drive.google.com/your-link-here";
final Uri url = Uri.parse(googleDriveLink);

try {
  bool launched = await launch(url.toString());
  if (!launched) {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
} catch (e) {
  throw 'Error launching URL: $e';
}
```

Ensure that you have the `url_launcher` package added to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  url_launcher: ^6.2.2
```

Comment: it's not work for me....